# Update SQL Server table based on values in a column

Tags: sql-server

I have 11 tables in my SQL Server database in which have the same columns, 10 are sub tables and 1 is the main table where the data in 10 tables will be merged. The 10 tables are constantly updating from time to time, below is the column that my 11 tables has:

```
[DATE], [SOURCE], [DESTINATION], [REFERENCE#], [ITEMCODE], [DESCRIPTION],
[UM], [PRICE], [QTY], [AMOUNT], [MFGDATE], [EXPDATE], [LOT#], [TRANS], [CONSIGNOR], [DRDATE]
```

When a user updates a table, i.e `Table1`, the main table should automatically bee updated based on the `SOURCE` and `DESTINATION` columns. I know that there is the `Merge` statement, where you can update, insert and delete all at the same time, but my problem with that is the delete, since `Table1` will only have partial data compared to the main table, it will delete the rest of the data in main table that is not present in the `Table1`.

I am new to SQL Server and I can't pull this off by myself, that's why I am here looking for ideas and some help too.

Comment: You can easily set up `MERGE` to **only** update existing rows - and **NOT** delete anything!

Comment: Why this design? I mean, why do you need the 11th table? Why not use a view?

Comment: Is it possible? sorry I don't know, that's why I am asking, something that it will look up source and destination in the main table and compare it in Table1 and update, insert and delete?

Comment: You can use a Trigger for that, but I won't use `MERGE` as @marc_s because it has [some issues](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/), instead I would use `EXISTS()`

Comment: Do all these tables have the same columns? Can you provide sample data as DDL and DML (create table and insert statements) and expected results?

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes, they do have the same columns, what I want is something that it will only look up source and destination in the main table and compare it to Table1, and then insert update or delete the main table if needed

Comment: "They do have the same columns" - in other words - this has the awful stench of a bad design all over it. With the exception of simple lookup tables, having multiple tables with the same columns means you mixing data and meta data. Instead of 11 identical tables, there should be only one single table, with an added column to indicate the difference in data. For instance, instead of "sales_shop1", "sales_shop2" and "sales_shop3" there should be a single table called "sales", that contain a column to indicate the shop.

Comment: each of the 10 tables represent different department which has different transactions, each table is being updated with an excel file used by each department, as I said in my post, this tables are constantly being updated from time to time, the main purpose of the main table is for data redundancy and for report generation.

Comment: Does a Partitioned view fit on your needs?? https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-partitioned-views/

Comment: "each of the 10 tables represent different department..." Great. Use a single table with another column to indicate the department. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after reading your comments and suggestion and also reading a lot more in other site, I have come up with this:

```
MERGE DelTrans2 as trgt
USING testTable1 src
    ON trgt.SOURCE = Src.SOURCE
    AND trgt.DESTINATION = Src.DESTINATION
    AND trgt.REFERENCE# = Src.REFERENCE#
    AND trgt.ITEMCODE = Src.ITEMCODE
    AND trgt.ID = Src.ID
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    AND Src.ID = 1001 THEN
    INSERT(DATE, SOURCE, DESTINATION, REFERENCE#, ITEMCODE, DESCRIPTION, UM, PRICE, QTY, AMOUNT, MFGDATE, EXPDATE, LOT#, TRANS, CONSIGNOR, DRDATE, ID)
    VALUES(DATE, SOURCE, DESTINATION, REFERENCE#, ITEMCODE, DESCRIPTION, UM, PRICE, QTY, AMOUNT, MFGDATE, EXPDATE, LOT#, TRANS, CONSIGNOR, DRDATE, ID)
WHEN MATCHED AND 
    (
        ISNULL(trgt.DATE, '') <> ISNULL(Src.DATE, '')
        OR
        ISNULL(trgt.SOURCE, '') <> ISNULL(Src.SOURCE, '')
        OR
        ISNULL(trgt.DESTINATION, '') <> ISNULL(Src.DESTINATION, '')
        OR
        ISNULL(trgt.REFERENCE#, '') <> ISNULL(Src.REFERENCE#, '')
        OR
        ISNULL(trgt.ITEMCODE, '') <> ISNULL(Src.ITEMCODE, '')
        OR
        ISNULL(trgt.DESCRIPTION, '') <> ISNULL(Src.DESCRIPTION, '')
        OR
        ISNULL(trgt.UM, '') <> ISNULL(Src.UM, '')
        OR
        ISNULL(trgt.PRICE, '') <> ISNULL(Src.PRICE, '')
        OR
        ISNULL(trgt.QTY, '') <> ISNULL(Src.QTY, '')
        OR
        ISNULL(trgt.AMOUNT, '') <> ISNULL(Src.AMOUNT, '')
        OR
        ISNULL(trgt.MFGDATE, '') <> ISNULL(Src.MFGDATE, '')
        OR
        ISNULL(trgt.EXPDATE, '') <> ISNULL(Src.EXPDATE, '')
        OR
        ISNULL(trgt.LOT#, '') <> ISNULL(Src.LOT#, '')
        OR
        ISNULL(trgt.TRANS, '') <> ISNULL(Src.TRANS, '')
        OR
        ISNULL(trgt.CONSIGNOR, '') <> ISNULL(Src.CONSIGNOR, '')
        OR
        ISNULL(trgt.DRDATE, '') <> ISNULL(Src.DRDATE, '')
        OR
        ISNULL(trgt.ID, '') <> ISNULL(Src.ID, '')
    )
    AND Src.ID = 1001
THEN
    UPDATE SET DATE = Src.DATE, SOURCE = Src.SOURCE, DESTINATION = Src.DESTINATION, REFERENCE# = Src.REFERENCE#, ITEMCODE = Src.ITEMCODE, DESCRIPTION = Src.DESCRIPTION, UM = Src.UM, PRICE = Src.PRICE, QTY = Src.QTY, AMOUNT = Src.AMOUNT, MFGDATE = Src.MFGDATE, EXPDATE = Src.EXPDATE, LOT# = Src.LOT#, TRANS = Src.TRANS, CONSIGNOR = Src.CONSIGNOR, DRDATE = Src.DRDATE, ID = Src.ID
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
    AND trgt.ID = 1001 THEN
    DELETE;
```

I know this is not the most efficient way, but this works fine with what I want.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using an after insert trigger on the `Table1` table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER your_trigger
ON Table1
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE a
    SET SOURCE = b.SOURCE, DESTINATION = b.DESTINATION
    FROM Main a
    INNER JOIN INSERTED b
        ON a.ID = b.ID
END
GO
```

I assume that `Table1` and the main table are connected via a column called `Id`.  However, you may update the join logic to use whichever column(s) should determine how to connect the two tables.